# Reading and IO port configured as a UART on a PIC16F916

Tags: pic, microchip

Is it possible to read the input on a PIC (in this case a [PIC16F916](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41250e.pdf)) when it is configured as UART RX?

RC7 is the RX pin on the PIC16F916, and I would like to be able to read the state of the pin while the UART is receiving data.

Comment: You should be able to read it like any other pin, the problem will be timing. You could get, depending on your data transmission speed and loop speed, missing transitions. I'm not sure if RC7 is a change-notification pin, but you may be able to set an interrupt for CN to catch edges, but I'm not sure if that works with UART being configured on that pin.

Comment: figures 3-20 and 3-21 seem to indicate that you can read the data on the pin at any time